# storing key value pair in multivalued field solr4.0

Tags: solr, solr4

i am using solr4.0. I want to store key value pairs of attributes in mutlivalued field.

Example: I have some documents (Products) which have attributes as one field and i indexed 
attributes as separate documents to power auto suggest . now in some auto suggest i have to show facet count of products also . For this i am using solr joins 4.0 and faceting on attributes. here i want to get the name and id of attributes. how i can achieve this?

The Query is looks like below

```
localhost:8980/solr/searchapp/select?q=%7B!join+from=attr_id+to=prod_attr_id%7Dterms:red&wt=json&indent=true&facet.field=prod_attr_id&facet=true&rows=1000&fl=product_name,product_id
```